# Array Splice does not preserve "trail_end"

Tags: php

I am a newbie and have a piece of Wordpress code which has a glitch in it.

Sorry if my question is silly, though the support from where I bought the theme seems to answer with a great delay.

I will paste it and maybe someone can help. If no one can figure out the problem I will delete the question.

The code adds a few changes to the **breadcrumb navigation** on my [site](http://www.inutritie.ro/product/xpand-xtreme-pump/).

**The problem I think is with this:**

```
// Add the trail back on to the end.
$links[] = $trail['trail_end'];

// Add the new links, and the original trail's end, back into the trail.
array_splice( $trail, 1, count( $trail ) - 1, $links );
```

**These two line of code should add a `<span class="trail-end"></span>` to the end of the breadcrumbs around the words "Xpand Xtreme Pump" (in my link example)**

Here is the code:

```
function woo_custom_breadcrumbs_trail_add_product_categories ( $trail ) {
    if ( ( get_post_type() == 'product' ) && is_singular() ) {
        global $post;

        $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
        $links = array();

        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $c ) {
                $parents = woo_get_term_parents( $c->term_id, $taxonomy, true, ', ', $c->name, array() );

                if ( $parents != '' && ! is_wp_error( $parents ) ) {
                    $parents_arr = explode( ', ', $parents );

                    foreach ( $parents_arr as $p ) {
                        if ( $p != '' ) { $links[] = $p; }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Add the trail back on to the end.
            $links[] = $trail['trail_end'];


            // Add the new links, and the original trail's end, back into the trail.
            array_splice( $trail, 1, count( $trail ) - 1, $links );

        }
    }

    return $trail;
} // End woo_custom_breadcrumbs_trail_add_product_categories()
```

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($trail)` before the `$links[] = ` command?

Comment: This is the output of the var_dup: array(3) { [0]=> string(150) "Home" [1]=> string(72) "Products" ["trail_end"]=> string(17) "Elite Mass Gainer" }

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($links)` before the `$links[]`?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(123) "Gainere" }

Comment: So you want the resulting menu to look like: Home -> Products -> Gainere -> Elite Mass Gainer? With all the links clickable except the last one?

Comment: Yes, the "Elite Mass Gainer" needs to have the span class <span class="trail-end"></span> so it will fit correctly in the breadcrumb. If you visit the link to my site published in the question you will see that the text "Elite Mass Gainer" is not aligned with the links. ty!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7212/discussion-between-mike-purcell-and-webmasters)

Comment: What I am trying to figure out is what the $links array is for. It only has the value 'Gainere', is this the root link which is not clickable, while everything in the $trail array is supposed to be clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
...

// Wrap the trail_end with your span tag
$trail['trail_end'] = '<span class="trail-end">' . end($trail) . '</span>';

// Add the trail back on to the end.
$links[] = $trail['trail_end'];

...
```

Remember, that this is a hack, I'd recommend doing this in the template rendering the bread-crumbs.